# Showing Error Value Cannot be null. While Adding Task from Gantt Chart for ASP.NET MVC with dhtmlxGantt

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Showing Error Value Cannot be null. While Adding Task from Gantt Chart for ASP.NET MVC with dhtmlxGantt.
An exception of type ‘System.ArgumentNullException’ occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.
Additional Information :Value cannot be null

LINK : [dhtmlx Link for Gantt Chart](https://dhtmlx.com/blog/using-dhtmlx-gantt-chart-asp-net-mvc/)

Heres My Code :

```
public static List<GanttRequest> Parse(FormCollection form, string ganttMode)
    {
        // save current culture and change it to InvariantCulture for data parsing
        var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        var dataActions = new List<GanttRequest>();
        var prefixes = form["ids"].Split(',');

        foreach (var prefix in prefixes)
        {
            var request = new GanttRequest();

            // lambda expression for form data parsing
            Func<string, string> parse = x => form[String.Format("{0}_{1}", prefix, x)];

            request.Mode = (GanttMode)Enum.Parse(typeof(GanttMode), ganttMode, true);
            request.Action = (GanttAction)Enum.Parse(typeof(GanttAction), parse("!nativeeditor_status"), true);
            request.SourceId = Int64.Parse(parse("id"));

            // parse gantt task
            if (request.Action != GanttAction.Deleted && request.Mode == GanttMode.Tasks)
            {
//--HERE SHOWING ERROR VALUE CANNOT BE NULL--//
                    request.UpdatedTask = new GanttTasks()
                    {
                        GanttTaskId = (request.Action == GanttAction.Updated) ? (int)request.SourceId : 0,
                        Text = parse("text"),
                        StartDate = DateTime.Parse(parse("start_date")),
                        Duration = Int32.Parse(parse("duration")),
                        Progress = Decimal.Parse(parse("progress")),
                        ParentId = (parse("parent") != "0") ? Int32.Parse(parse("parent")) : (int?)null,
                        SortOrder = (parse("order") != null) ? Int32.Parse(parse("order")) : 0,
                        Type = parse("type")
                    };
            }
            // parse gantt link
            else if (request.Action != GanttAction.Deleted && request.Mode == GanttMode.Links)
            {
                request.UpdatedLink = new GanttLinks()
                {
                    GanttLinkId = (request.Action == GanttAction.Updated) ? (int)request.SourceId : 0,
                    SourceTaskId = Int32.Parse(parse("source")),
                    TargetTaskId = Int32.Parse(parse("target")),
                    Type = parse("type")
                };
            }

            dataActions.Add(request);
        }

        // return current culture back
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;

        return dataActions;
    }
}
```

I Referred to link provided above and done as stated. But while adding value its shows value cannot be null.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a default value for task.progress on the client side,

JS:

```
gantt.attachEvent("onTaskCreated", function(task){
    task.progress = 0;
    return true;
});
```

Client doesn't set the default value for progress property of a newly created task, so when you insert task on a backend progress value is null.
And since backend code doesn't validate the value, probably the error fires on this line:

```
Progress = Decimal.Parse(parse("progress")),
```

Setting a default value on the client, as shown above, or checking for null on the server should fix the issue